# AWK Remove lines that have the same value in fields 1,...,n but differ in the value of the n+1 field except if they are unique

Tags: awk

I have `file1.tsv` which looks like this:

```
1    ABC    10    XYZ    Null    Null
1    ABC    10    XYZ    1000    FFGG
1    ABC    10    XYZ    1001    FFHH
2    DEF    11    UVW    Null    Null
3    GHI    30    RST    Null    Null
3    GHI    30    RST    1002    JJKK
3    GHI    30    RST    1003    JJLL
```

I would like `awk` to print to `file2.tsv` the output:

```
1    ABC    10    XYZ    1000    FFGG
1    ABC    10    XYZ    1001    FFHH
2    DEF    11    UVW    Null    Null
3    GHI    30    RST    1002    JJKK
3    GHI    30    RST    1003    JJLL
```

That is, removing (not printing) line 1 and line 5 because they are not unique consdering ONLY the values of fields `$1-$4` and because `$5="Null"`and `$6="Null"`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if ALL lines had Null for $4 and $5? Then you'd get no output at all when $1-$4 are duplicates - is that desirable?

Comment: No, that is no desirable and that is not the case. Only $5 and $6 may have Nulls

Comment: Of course I meant $5 and $6. Think.

Comment: Well, in the hypothetical situation in which ALL lines had Null for $5 and $6, my desired output would be one line per repeated block. That is achieved with this simple command `awk '!x[$0]++'` 
This command would print line 1, 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1):

Don't print lines where ABC or GHI matches Null.

awk '/ABC|GHI/~!/Null/' file

```
1    ABC    10    XYZ    1000    FFGG
1    ABC    10    XYZ    1001    FFHH
2    DEF    11    UVW    Null    Null
3    GHI    30    RST    1002    JJKK
3    GHI    30    RST    1003    JJLL
```

Comment: can u explain ur solution?

Comment: Thank you for your answer Claes Wikner. The problem is that this is a simplified version of my file. My file contains thousands of lines and this approach is not feasible.